# How to print quotation mark glyphs inside the verbatim, minted, listings & texttt?

Tags: listings, verbatim, minted, typewriter, quotation

Assuming the desired quotation marks in the code are called *glyphs*, how to print the left & the right quotes as desired, as it's printed in `monster'
inside the verbatim, minted, listings environments & the texttt?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{minted}
\usepackage{listings}
\begin{document}

Is the right quote printed as desired ' Yep.

Is the left quote printed as desired  ` Yep.
\begin{verbatim}
Is it printed in verbatim as desired? '  I don't think so.
\end{verbatim}

\begin{minted}{c++}
// Here's a C code called `monster'
// Is it printed as desired? Nope.
\end{minted}

\begin{lstlisting}[language=c++]
// Here's a C code called `monster'
// Is it printed as desired? Nope.
\end{lstlisting}

\texttt{Let's try our last chance using texttt: `monster' No luck!}\\

It just doesn't print `monster' as desired\\

It keeps on printing those ugly looking \texttt{`} and \texttt{'} instead.\\

How to print the left \& the right quotes as it's printed in `monster'
inside the verbatim, minted, listing environments \& the texttt? 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: the output is imho correct. The main point of verbatim is to show the input, and so if you input U+0060 you should get U+0060 in the output and not U+2018, even if it looks nicer, and similar for  U+0027 and U+2019. If you want ‘ you should input it (with listings this will probably need a literate setting)

Comment: in verbatim constructs `\`xxx'`  produce \`xxx'  and `‘xxx’` produces ‘xxx’

Comment: @UlrikeFischer That sounds quite right, I have to input that special "glyph" quotation mark chars directly on the keyboard. I'm using a Mac wireless keyboard and it has no such  chars  even using the Alt and Shift combination. The  Mac has a so-called Character Viewer I saw those glyph quotation mark chars there, copied them pasted them into the verbatim blocks and it worked out finally! I'm glad this has worked out. So it looks like I got this problem all wrong from the start. I had to literally enter those "glyph" chars from the keyboard. As simple as that :)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Yep the verbatim does its job there properly but for the neophyte the way the TeX works looks quite often perplexing  :)